# Google Maps API - Even if I enabled the bill account i get an errror message

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-maps, divi

I'm using the Google Maps Api to insert a custom maps on a customer's website, even if I insert the bill account and a credit card now i get the message 'this website not loading correctly google maps. Are you the Owner of this website?'.
I inserted the maps using javascript following the guide provided by Google, the code is insert using a Divi's code module on a Wordpress installation.
I added this map one year ago and everything was showned correctly.
If I click on OK then i can see the maps correctly, how can I get rid of this message?

Comment: Any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with creating a new API key:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key